# Jquery Finder-like Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, finder

I need to make a site's menu navigate like OSX's Finder in column view, where each level appears next to its parent in a vertical column.

Have been googling this for a couple of hours now, and [this Jquery plugin seems to be the closest match](https://github.com/jobelenus/columnview/) (There's a [demo here](http://john.theoradical.net/columnview/demo.html))

From a first trial, it seems somewhat hard to customize. I need it to behave and look differently in a couple of ways:

- no scrolls, neither vertical nor horizontal. it needs to act more like a web menu than like a select box
- when clicking on the final link, after navigating the subs, the whole page should be redirected to the url, and the menu should keep the state.
- the final link should be clickable right away, like on the demo. on my trial, it loads yet another column with a duplicate of the link, which in turn is clickable.

Does anybody know how to accomplish these with this plugin, or could point me towards simpler implementations that are closer to these specs?

Here's the menu html structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current" id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo">
        <a href="/o-que-estamos-fazendo/">O que estamos fazendo</a>
        <ul id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo-children">
            <li id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo-children-ficcao">
                <a href="/o-que-estamos-fazendo/ficcao/">Ficção</a>
            </li>
            <li class="current" id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo-children-documentario">
                <a href="/o-que-estamos-fazendo/documentario/">Documentário</a>
                <ul id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo-children-documentario-children">
                    <li class="current" id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo-children-documentario-children-josephine-king">
                        <a href="/o-que-estamos-fazendo/documentario/josephine-king/">Josephine King</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo-children-televiso">
                <a href="/o-que-estamos-fazendo/televiso/">Televisão</a>
            </li>
            <li id="nav-o-que-estamos-fazendo-children-museus">
                <a href="/o-que-estamos-fazendo/museus/">Museus</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-o-que-ja-fizemos">
        <a href="/o-que-ja-fizemos/">O que já fizemos</a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-o-que-somos">
        <a href="/o-que-somos/">O que somos</a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-quem-somos-contato">
        <a href="/quem-somos-contato/">Quem somos | contato</a>
    </li>
    <li id="nav-mirabolancias">
        <a href="/mirabolancias/">Mirabolâncias</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As generated by the 'nav' liquid tag on [Harmonyapp](http://docs.harmonyapp.com/harmony-templates/template-tags/#object-nav))

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple solution. all you have to imagine is that the columns are just like a regular drop down (drop left in our situation). Simply hide all the child elements, and trigger their 'show()' when the parent of an item is clicked.

basic css:

```
div#finderMenu{width: 800px}
ul{overflow: auto} /* will deal with your scrollbar issue */
ul li ul{float: left; height: 200px; width: 100px;} /* will layout all child uls */
li.current{background: blue} /* will make current parent button blue */
```

basic jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul>li').click(function(){
        //hide all initial menu blocks
        $('ul ul').hide();

        //this will deal with the clickables and current states
        $('.active').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        //now for the menu items
        $('.showing').removeClass('showing').hide();
        $(' ul', this).addClass('showing').show();
    });
});
```

obviously you'd flesh out the css to make it look pretty and contain it all within a div. but I think you get the idea :)

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for this, I prefer it simpler this way too. will try it today or tomorrow and confirm. would also like to add a slide/ease effect to this, is there a preferred jquery effect lib or plugin for this?

Comment: just an update - this hasn't worked for me so far. I'm trying to contact the columnview plugin author to see if he's available for this customization.